# Any good tools for skimming over a set of icons?

Tags: icons

I have a set of 1400 icons and need a good way of previewing them and determining which one is needed from time to time. Are there any good programs out there to do this? Windows Explorer sorta sucks for it because every time I have to wait for all the icons to be loaded when scrolling through the huge list.

Answer (score 0):

[Axialis IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) is good icon editor and manager.